# Директории drawable и mipmap в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-resources, mipmaps

Меня интересует такой вопрос: у меня в `Android Studio` есть только папка `drawable`, нету папок `drawable-hdpi, ...-mdpi, ...-xhdpi, ...-xxhdpi`. Мне их нужно создать? Но есть `mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi`. Куда нужно загружать иконки, которые я хочу использовать в своём проекте? Спасибо.

Comment: Mipmap, насколько я понял, - специальный формат для текстур. Не знаю, можно ли их использовать, как обычные иконки... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Да, нужно создать. Правой клик на каталоге "res" - new - android resource directory.

Графика с mipmap появились в android 4.3 [Mipmapping for drawables](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#MipMap). Флаг позвозволяет в некоторых случаях получить лучшее качество картинок при уменьшении за счет большего потребления памяти.

Последние лучшие практики от google говорят, что иконки приложения лучше держать в mipmap-, а не в drawable-. Можно смело им следовать, проблем на старых версиях android с ними не возникнет.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение.